# What do I need to replace after water damage during construction of a new home?

Tags: drywall, water-damage

While setting our new T style modular ranch style home we had a large amount of rain come before they had the sections set and now have water laying in some sections of drywall in almost every room. I think the builder is going to dry as much as possible but I'm concerned about future problems with the drywall. I guess my question is how much water on drywall is acceptable before needing replaced. Most of the wet areas are the internal walls on every room ceiling corners. I can press my fingernail in the wet spots and it is pretty mushy. A few of the light switch boxes are wet underneath too from water following the wires. Some areas I know has insulation that is definitely getting replaced but the visible slightly wet areas I'm not sure what I should try to make them do. The builder says they want us 100% satisfied so trying to decide whether to have them replace all drywall that is wet before we go any further.

Answer (score 3):

I'd drive to get anything that was wet replaced. For 100% sure get anything that felt "mushy" replaced. Any wet insulation needs to be replaced too. Any wood that is wet should be allowed to dry up before covering it back over.

Comment: +1 I'd also check any wood for warping after it's dried. And keep an eye out for rust starting on nail heads.

Answer (score 2):

I just lived and worked through "sandy" here on the east coast of NJ.  The sheet rock was not something we "dried out." We cut it out a few inches above the parts exposed to water all the way around.  Depending on the water level we replaced 1', 2', or 4' of sheet rock.  In some places floor to ceiling had to be replaced.

Either you or the builder should be insured for something like this, in fact, shouldn't they be taking measures to prevent this from happening?  This isn't something I would tolerate in a home I planned on moving into or owning.

Don't "allow" anything to dry out if you had standing water.  It should be opened up by removing the sheetrock and then a professional remediation company should come in with heaters, air movers, and dehumidifiers and get the wood to the proper humidity or you risk mold growth.  Depending on how wet it got and what type of insulation you have it may not need to be replaced.

Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

I would want all the drywall in the exterior wall removed and all the ceilings replaced. The insulation will stay wet for weeks in the wall and cause mold.

If they wont agree to that make holes high and low in the exterior walls about 3 inches so  you can stick your hand and in and feel insulation for moisture. A hole can be easily patched.